# Setting RDS to 'publicly available' to 'YES'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I just finished setting up an RDS instance but I couldn't connect to it using sql workbench.

What I did was I set 'publicly available' to 'YES' and I was able to connect to it.

I'm new to this and would appreciate some guidance with regards to the actions that I did.

Are there any risk of having it available to public? currently, I only have my IP as the only allowed traffic.

Comment: You've just exposed your database to the public internet where anyone can try to directly log into it.  That's very risky.  Keep it private and i suggest using VPN to connect to your network within AWS.

Comment: @MattS except only his IP address is allowed by the network firewall (AWS Security Group) in front of the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowing your RDS instance to be publicly accessible by only your own IP is fine.

If you only need part time access to your server, I would add and remove my IP address from the security group as needed. I use hand written batch scripts to do this.

If your RDS instance does not need real public access except for SQL WorkBench, then I would setup OpenVPN, keep RDS private and do all my work over a VPN. OpenVPN makes all of this very easy. Automatically routes my traffic destined for my VPC over the VPN using private IP addresses.

With this week's announcemnt of inter-region VPC peering, there is even less need for making non-web servers public.

[Announcing Support for Inter-Region VPC Peering](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/announcing-support-for-inter-region-vpc-peering/)